# GoogleProtobuf repeated messages

Tags: c++, proto

I have a .proto file which consists of following messages:

```
message A {
    message B {
        optional string Header = 1;
        optional string Value = 2;
    }
    repeated B Inputs = 1;
}
message BuildConfig {
    optional A Options = 1;
}
```

In my pb.h file there are following functions:

***class BuildConfig:***

```
inline const ::google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField< ::NBuildModels::NProto::A >&
      GetOptions() const { return options(); }
```

***class A:***

```
inline const ::google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField< ::NBuildModels::NProto::A_B >&
      GetInputs() const { return inputs(); }
```

I am trying to access Head and Value like this:

```
void foo(const NBuildModels::NProto::BuildConfig& config) {
auto a = config.GetOptions();
auto b = a.GetInputs();
}
```

However, it does not work with the following error : No member named 'GetInputs' in 'google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrFieldNBuildModels::NProto::A'

Answer (score 0):

What protobuf syntax do you use? What `protogen` do you use? Neither of known me `protogen` generates the C++ methods `GetOptions` and `GetInputs`. This works for me after Google `protogen` with `syntax = "proto3";`:

```
auto& a = config.options();
auto& b = a.inputs();
```